# SQL Server 2008R2 trigger sometimes doesn't fire

Tags: sql-server, trigger

We use wireless barcode scanners to scan our goods as they wind their way around the factory, scanning each product at fifteen separate checkpoints.  After passing through a checkpoint, the product gets a STATUS ID which corresponds to the relevant checkpoint.

The scanners pass the status ID, Barcode of the product, Scanner name, and date/time to a table called HW_SCANNER_TRANSACTIONS and the trigger then updates other tables before updating the original table with a date and time that the trigger ran.

Recently, we have been seeing errors where the data is verified as in the scanner_transactions table but has not updated the other tables.  There appears to be no pattern to these.

```
USE [DBMAIN]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TRANSACTIONS_InsertTrigger]    Script Date: 09/02/2015 09:02:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRANSACTIONS_InsertTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[HW_SCANNER_TRANSACTIONS] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 

BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON 
UPDATE [GLA_FRAME_LABEL]  
SET ITEM_STATUS_ID =  inserted.StatusID
FROM inserted
WHERE substring(inserted.[BarcodeID],2,15) = [GLA_FRAME_LABEL].[LABEL_ID]

UPDATE [QUOTE_ITEM]   
SET ITEM_STATUS_ID  =  inserted.StatusID
FROM inserted
WHERE [QUOTE_ITEM_ID] =  (SELECT QUOTE_ITEM.QUOTE_ITEM_ID FROM QUOTE_ITEM INNER JOIN GLA_FRAME_LABEL ON 
QUOTE_ITEM.QUOTE_ITEM_ID = GLA_FRAME_LABEL.QUOTE_ITEM_ID WHERE (GLA_FRAME_LABEL.LABEL_ID = SUBSTRING ( inserted .BarcodeID,2,15)))

UPDATE [GLA_FRAME_LABEL]
SET ITEM_STATUS_ID  =  inserted.StatusID
FROM inserted
WHERE [QUOTE_ITEM_ID]  =  (SELECT QUOTE_ITEM_ID FROM GLA_FRAME_LABEL WHERE LABEL_ID = SUBSTRING ( inserted .BarcodeID,2,15)) 
AND QTY_COUNT = (SELECT QTY_COUNT FROM GLA_FRAME_LABEL Where LABEL_ID = SUBSTRING ( inserted .BarcodeID,2,15))

UPDATE [HW_SCANNER_TRANSACTIONS]  
SET [Synched] = GETUTCDATE() 
FROM inserted
WHERE inserted.idx =[HW_SCANNER_TRANSACTIONS].[idx]  

END;
```

When the errors occur, the only update that runs is the final one in the list which updates the transaction table synch date to say that it's been run.

I'm at a loss to explain why and wondering if there was anything wrong or needed adding to my trigger to make it work.

Comment: Is "sometimes" when the insert that fires the trigger involves multiple rows vs. a single row? Your joins don't look quite correct to me - a correlated join is usually in the form `UPDATE t1 SET t1.col = t2.col FROM dbo.t1 INNER JOIN dbo.t2 ON ...;` It's possible you're getting an arbitrary row from the join updated instead of all of them.